# Redis performance issues?

Tags: performance, node.js, redis

I was trying to put some heavy load on my Redis for testing purposes and find out any upper limits. First I loaded it with 50,000 and 100,000 keys of size 32characters with values around 32 characters. It took no more than 8-15 seconds in both key sizes. Now I try to put 4kb of data as value for each key. First 10000 keys take 800 milli seconds to set. But from that point it slows down gradually and to set whole 50,000 keys it takes aroudn 40 minutes. I am loading the database using NodeJs with [node_redis (Mranney)](http://github.com/mranney/node_redis) . Is there any mistake I am doing or is Redis just that slow with big values of size 4 KB?

One more thing I found now is when I run another client parallel to the current one and update keys this 2nd client finishes up loading the 50000 keys with 4kb values within 8 seconds while the first client still does its thing forever. Is it a bug in node or the redis library? This is alarming and not acceptable for production.

Comment: Hmm.. I installed hiredis but I don't know if it is automatically loaded into program when i do require('redis'). Is that the issue?

Comment: To verify if you have the hiredis module installed, you can run node, and then do `require ("hiredis")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to get some kind of back pressure for doing bulk writes from node into Redis.  By default, node will queue all writes and does not enforce an upper bound on the outgoing queue size.

node_redis has a "drain" event that you can listen for to implement some rudimentary back pressure.

Comment: Hi Matt, I tried to look at client.command_queue.length and stop until I get a "drain" event. But client.command_queue.length is always 0. So I was checking client.offline_queue.length which gives me proper number but the drain event gets fired only once. I'll try it again and get back with code. Thanks.

Comment: I have attached the code here https://gist.github.com/945441 . This doesn't seem to be the proper way to backpressure?

Comment: There are a couple of different issues here.  The first is that pre-connection commands are queued.  The second is that once you have a connection, another queue is maintained for commands sent but for which a reply has not yet been received.  I've added an example of a general way to deal with both cases here: https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/blob/master/examples/backpressure_drain.js

Answer (score 3):

The default redis configuration is not optimized for that sort of usage. I suspect you have it swapping to disk with a page size of 32 bytes, which means that each key added has to find 128 contiguous free pages and may end up using system VM or needing to expand the swap file a lot.

When you update a key, the space is already allocated so you don't see any performance issues.

Comment: This is just for testing purposes so I do not care much. But what if such demand occur in real time and my application needs to store so much data? Is there any configuration I can change to match my requirement?

Comment: Also even before the first client has created all 50000 keys If I run 2nd client it goes ahead and finishes prior to the 1st one. So what you said may not be the issue I am facing.

Comment: Page size and memory usage are configurable - check the comments in redis.conf. The second client finishing doesn't necessarily rule out that scenario - the combination of low memory conditions and concurrency can get quite complex, especially if timeouts and automatic retries are involved. For example, could it be resetting all the previous keys every time it runs into an error?

Comment: Hmm.. it could be! Will research over this issue. Because my application is expected to handle many concurrent sessions stored into redis database and I can not allow this uncertainty :(.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was doing lot of set (Key value) in NodeJs which is done asynchronously, lot of socket connections are concurrently open. The NodeJs socket write buffer might be overloaded and GC might come and fiddle with the node process.

PS: I changed redis memory configurations as Tom suggested but it was still performing the same.